# Does SKIP LOCKED FOR UPDATE work with views?

Tags: postgresql

I am currently using `SKIP LOCKED FOR UPDATE` to schedule tasks as such:

```
UPDATE task
SET started_at = NOW()
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM task
  WHERE /* ... bunch of logic ... */
  LIMIT 1
  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
)
RETURNING id
```

I would like to abstract the sub-query used to select outstanding tasks using a view, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW outstanding_task AS
SELECT *
FROM task
WHERE /* ... bunch of logic ... */
```

and then use the view to pick tasks for scheduling, e.g.

```
UPDATE task
SET started_at = NOW()
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM outstanding_task
  LIMIT 1
  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
)
RETURNING id
```

Does `SKIP LOCKED FOR UPDATE` work with views in this setup?, i.e. Does it guarantee that the same ID will not be picked?

How to test it to be sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work as expected.

To test it, start two sessions and use explicit transactions, e.g.

Session 1:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM outstanding_task WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

Session 2:

```
-- Here SKIP LOCKED is optional.
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM outstanding_task WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

Assuming there is an outstanding task with `id=1`, then the first transaction should return a row and the second one should not.